# crash log, when get product list from iap

Tags: ios, crash, cocos2d-x, in-app-purchase

I got a crash log from my app user. This user wants to open the IAP product list, then my app is crashed. I looked into the log and my code. I don't know why my app is crashed.

```
Incident Identifier: 7D3A789B-8E4A-40BA-BF10-B0387707E2E7
CrashReporter Key:   da62ff31c65c542560bc99919be673cc101c6962
Hardware Model:      iPhone5,2
Process:             bomb [2828]
Path:                /var/mobile/Applications/5CB84CE5-CA70-4D26-954A-3E22756754E5/bomb.app/bomb
Identifier:          com.lmj.bomb
Version:             5 (1.0.8)
Code Type:           ARM (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2013-10-31 11:15:13.146 +0800
OS Version:          iOS 7.0.2 (11A501)
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Triggered by Thread:  0

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x2f871e86 0x2f79d000 + 872070
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x39b6c6c2 0x39b64000 + 34498
2   CoreFoundation                  0x2f871dc8 0x2f79d000 + 871880
3   bomb                            0x00723b7c SignalHandler + 132
4   libsystem_platform.dylib        0x3a17e716 0x3a17b000 + 14102
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3a183a4e 0x3a180000 + 14926
6   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a0cd028 0x3a083000 + 303144
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x3951b98a 0x3951b000 + 2442
8   libc++abi.dylib                 0x395321f4 0x3951b000 + 94708
9   libc++abi.dylib                 0x39531a04 0x3951b000 + 92676
10  libstdc++.6.dylib               0x39ea74ae 0x39ea1000 + 25774
11  libstdc++.6.dylib               0x39ecc52a 0x39ea1000 + 177450
12  libstdc++.6.dylib               0x39ed6264 0x39ea1000 + 217700
13  bomb                            0x003a7d22 -[IAPManager productsRequest:didReceiveResponse:] (IAPManager.mm:115)
14  StoreKit                        0x31f8d132 0x31f86000 + 28978
15  libdispatch.dylib               0x3a0510fe 0x3a050000 + 4350
16  libdispatch.dylib               0x3a0510ea 0x3a050000 + 4330
17  libdispatch.dylib               0x3a0539a4 0x3a050000 + 14756
18  CoreFoundation                  0x2f83c5b4 0x2f79d000 + 652724
19  CoreFoundation                  0x2f83ae80 0x2f79d000 + 646784
20  CoreFoundation                  0x2f7a553c 0x2f79d000 + 34108
21  CoreFoundation                  0x2f7a531e 0x2f79d000 + 33566
22  GraphicsServices                0x344dc2e6 0x344d5000 + 29414
23  UIKit                           0x3205c1e0 0x31fec000 + 459232
24  bomb                            0x000a312a main (main.m:14)
25  bomb                            0x0009dcb4 start + 36
```

I re-symbolicated the log and found some clue

```
[IAPManager productsRequest:didReceiveResponse:] (IAPManager.mm:115)
```

the line 115 is

```
wrapProduct->setLocalizedTitle(ccs([product.localizedTitle UTF8String]));
```

the following is the method code

```
- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response
{

    //NSArray *myProducts = response.products;
    NSArray *myProducts = response.products;
    //NSLog(@"产品Product ID:%@",response.invalidProductIdentifiers);
    //NSLog(@"产品付费数量: %d", [myProducts count]);
    // populate UI
    IAPClient::sharedIAPClient()->getProductList()->removeAllObjects();

    myProducts=[myProducts sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
        SKProduct *p1=obj1;
        SKProduct *p2=obj2;
        return [p1.price compare:p2.price];
        //        if ( [p1.price compare:p2.price] ) {
        //            return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedAscending;
        //        } else {
        //            return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedDescending;
        //        }
    }];
    for(SKProduct *product in myProducts){
        Product *wrapProduct=new Product;
        wrapProduct->setProductIdentifier(ccs([product.productIdentifier UTF8String]));
        wrapProduct->setLocalizedTitle(ccs([product.localizedTitle UTF8String]));
        wrapProduct->setLocalizedDescription(ccs([product.localizedDescription UTF8String]));
        wrapProduct->setLocalizedPrice(ccs([[product localizedPrice] UTF8String]));
        wrapProduct->setPrice([product.price floatValue]);
        IAPClient::sharedIAPClient()->getProductList()->addObject(wrapProduct);
        wrapProduct->release();
    }

    [request autorelease];
    IAPClient::sharedIAPClient()->gotProductData();
}
```

I have no idea about it. Can anyone give me some advice?

Comment: how do you create the request? I find the autorelease slightly suspicious. Since this is a callback method there's always the possibility that internally the request is used after the callback method ran.

Comment: This is my code to create the request.
```SKProductsRequest *request= [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:
                                 productIdentifiers];
    request.delegate = self;
    [request start];``` ps: I read many your blogs and your book to study cocos2d. Thank your for your blogs and book

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple is returning a nil value for product.localizedTitle.  We are seeing this across multiple games as well.  This is new (BAD!) behavior that just started happening last night.

Comment: We've encountered the same issue!! the app is already in the Store, and only works for AppleIDs using the US store. Changing the Store for that AppleID to UK or Australian stores, and the app crashes at the "localizedDescription"! which we're expecting but seems to be NULL!

Comment: Got it. Then I have to check the localizedDescription is NULL